# Auto re-generate of Keys reflected in Azure Key Vault Secret

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I have managed to create auto re-generate process between 'key1' and 'key2' with a gap of 1 day.

I have Key1 as a connection string within the Key Vault as secret when the Key does auto re-generate how do I reflect that change within the Key Vault secret?
The Key Vault is used within the Data Factory Pipeline.

```
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.Id -RoleDefinitionName 'Storage Account Key Operator Service Role' -Scope $storage.Id
$userPrincipalId = $(Get-AzADUser -SearchString 'Bob Johnson').Id
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'AzureBlobVault' -ObjectId $userPrincipalId -PermissionsToStorage get, list, delete, set, update, regeneratekey, getsas, listsas, deletesas, setsas, recover, backup, restore, purge
$regenerationPeriod = [System.Timespan]::FromDays(1)
Add-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName 'AzureBlobVault' -StorageAccountName 'john' -AccountResourceId '/subscriptions/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/John' -ActiveKeyName 'key1' -RegenerationPeriod $regenerationPeriod'


The Result:

Id                  : https://azurekeyvaultblob.vault.azure.net:443/storage/john
Vault Name          : AzureBlobVault
AccountName         : john
Account Resource Id : /subscriptions/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/john
Active Key Name     : key1
Auto Regenerate Key : True
Regeneration Period : 1.00:00:00
Enabled             : True
```

Comment: According to my understanding, is that you want  Azure key vault to manage connection string?

Comment: @Jim Xu. I am using my Blob Storage connection string in Key Vault within my pipeline and I also wanted the connection string within Key Vault to change when it regenerates new Keys.

Comment: Do you have any other concern on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, at the moment, we only can ask Key Vault to generate shared access signature tokens. If you want to do that, you can use the following the script

```
$sctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey Key1
$start = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$end = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(1)
$at = New-AzStorageAccountSasToken -Service blob,file,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Protocol HttpsOnly -StartTime $start -ExpiryTime $end -Context $sctx
Set-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition -AccountName $storageAccount.StorageAccountName  -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name accountsas -TemplateUri $at -SasType 'account' -ValidityPeriod ([System.Timespan]::FromDays(1))
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys#create-and-generate-tokens) and the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-2.5.0)

Besides, if you only want to use the connection string, I think you need to write code or script to manage it. For example, I use powershell script:

```
$name = "your account"
$password = "your passowrd"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $mycreds

$accountName ="your storage account name"
$keyvaultNmae="your key vault name"
$secretNmae="your secret name"
$accoutGroupName="your storage account group name"

$key=(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $accoutGroupName -Name $accountName)[0].Value 
$string= 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=' + $accountName + ';AccountKey=' + $Key + ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net' 

$secretVaule= $Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $string -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultNmae -Name $secretNmae -SecretValue  $secretVaule

$vaule= (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultNmae -Name $secretNmae).SecretValueText

Write-Output $vaule
```

Then I host the PowerShell script on [Azure Automation runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) and create a [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules) to run it